# Need help getting the data validation criteria from "list from a range" in an apps script so I can cycle through those values

Tags: validation, google-sheets, criteria

I want to get the data validation criteria from "list from a range" in an apps script so I can cycle through those values. For example, in cell A5 I have data validation set up, with "criteria" being "List from a range" and the corresponding range being "'Grade K Class MTSS Profile'!B2:AH2". I want it to return "'Grade K Class MTSS Profile'!B2:AH2" so I can cycle through this range and do something with the cells contained in that range.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  .createMenu('MTSS Tools')
  .addItem('Save All Student Reports', 'saveAllStudentReports')
  .addToUi();
}


function saveAllStudentReports() {

var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A4');
var rule = cell.getDataValidation();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

if (rule != null) {
  var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
  var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
  ui.alert("Has rule");
  ui.alert('The data validation rule is ' + criteria + args);
}
else
{
  ui.alert("NO rule");
}
}
```

However, I'm not getting the actual range. Ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#getCriteriaValues()):

**getCriteriaValues returns:**

> Object[] — an array of arguments appropriate to the rule's criteria type; the number of arguments and their type match the corresponding require...() method of the DataValidation class

So `args` is a Range object, which means all methods from the [Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) can be used, like [getA1Notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation):

```
ui.alert('The data validation rule is ' + criteria + ' ' + args[0].getA1Notation()
```

Comment: Thank you. Being fairly new to this type of programming, I was looking at the same documentation and didn't know what "the number of arguments and their type match the corresponding require...() method of the DataValidation class" because when I look at the documentation for the DataValidation class I don't see the word "require". 

Your example works. I also need the sheet name the range goes with. So, I tried displaying:

args[0].getDataSourceTables()[0].getDataSource().getSpec();

thinking that would give me the name of the associated sheet, but I get an error msg. I'll keep trying.

Comment: You can get the name of the Sheet using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()`  Documentation: [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getname)

Comment: Thank you. I have used that method already to get the name of the active sheet. However, part of what I was asking in the original question was how to get "list from a range" when that range is in another sheet (the 'Grade K Class MTSS Profile' part). Essentially, I want to cycle through that range in the other sheet, but I need the other sheet name in order to do it.

Comment: I answered my own question with your help. I used: args[0].getSheet().getName() and it worked. Thank you for all of your help!!